# How to Fix 404 Error in Codeigniter PHP Framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

I have a website `http://www.example.com`.
Lots of links this website are show:

> 404 Error.

For Example here i show my Website 404 URL Link;

http://www.example.com/index.php?/hybrid-mobile-app-development.php

How to Fix this issues?

Comment: Are your routes setup in config/routes.php? Also unless you have it setup to use a file extension you would not need to add the .php at the end.

Answer (score 0):

404 error indicate you try to access file or page that not available for that directory or folder..

so you check your page or file that available Directory that path give..

Answer (score 0):

try this .htaccess file in your root folder

1) .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

2) and remove index.php from config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I hope this will work for you.